# Excel Formula for number of days active in a fiscal quarter

Tags: excel-formula

Fiscal quarter Q1 is 2/4/18 to 5/5/18. The dates change based on the quarter and so I have a table where I have the quarter number, start and end date of the quarter. 
Term date is 4/2/18. So the number of days this person is active in Q1 should be 58. If the term date is 5/7, number of days active in Q1 should be 91. 
How do I write this in a formula?

Comment: If a fiscal month is 28 days, how come the quarter goes to 5 May? That does not add up. Please [edit] your question and post a screenshot with the desired result. Please format the dates to write out the month, so we all know if 2/4 is April or Feburary.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the range you mentioned into account and not the 28 days range, written the following formula,

```
=IF(AND(E2>=$B$2,E2<=$C$2),E2-$B$2+1,IF(AND(E2>=$B$3,E2<=$C$3),E2-$B$3+1,IF(AND(E2>=$B$4,E2<=$C$4),E2-$B$4+1,IF(AND(E2>=$B$5,E2<=$C$5),E2-$B$5+1,"Date Out of Range"))))
```

[image: Fiscal_Data]

Hope this helps you.